# creating an array of objects using a custom constructor that throws errors

Tags: c++

Just like the title says I am trying to initialize a static array of objects(Route). The constructor throws an error if a condition is not met. This stops the rest of the array from initializing. Is there a way to "try" each element trying to be added to the array?

```
try {
        Route routes[] = {
                Route(legArray[0]) ,
                Route(routes[0], legArray[1]),
                Route(routes[1], legArray[2]),
                Route(routes[2], legArray[3]),
                Route(routes[3], legArray[4]),
                Route(routes[4], legArray[5]),
                Route(routes[5], legArray[6]),
                Route(routes[6], legArray[7]),
                Route(routes[7], legArray[8]),
                Route(routes[8], legArray[9])

        };
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(routes)/sizeof(*routes); i++) {
            routes[i].output();
        }
    }
    catch (const char* a) {
        cout << a << endl;
    }
```

To give some extra information, this is a program that calculates each Leg of a route. The constructor in question is:

```
Route::Route(const Route& r, const Leg& l)
    :totalDis(r.totalDis + l.distance)
{

    if (!strcmp(r.legs.back()->endCity, l.startCity)) {
        throw "Cities dont match!";
    }
    
    Route::legs = r.legs;

    Route::legs.push_back(&l);
 
}
```

Some commenters are dead on. There is two contractor for `Route`. the one posted above is a secondary.

Here are the `class` for the Route and Leg objects:

```
 class Leg {
private:
    const char* const startCity;
    const char* const endCity;
    const double distance;

public:
    Leg(const char* const, const char* const, const double);
    Leg& operator=(const Leg&);
    double getDistance() const;

    friend class Route;

};

class Route {
    vector<const Leg*> legs;
    const double totalDis = 0;
public:
    Route(const Leg&);
    Route(const Route&, const Leg&); //<--This is the constructor in question. 
    Route& operator=(const Route&);
    double getDistance() const;
    void output() const;
};
```

Comment: the size of an array - it is compile time thing. Calling constructor and an exception - run time things. So, it is impossible.

Comment: You might use a `std::vector` instead and initialise the elements one after another in a loop – and add appropriate exception handling there...

Comment: or create some wrapper function, that will return "empty object" when the constructor generates exception. But it depends on task.

Comment: Another variant: If your `Route` class has a non-throwing default constructor and a separate initialisation function you could separate initialisation (from within a loop then) from construction – and if not you might, if possible, modify `Route` class accordingly. Would rather go with the vector approach, though.

Comment: How would you handle these non-constructed array elements anyway? How would you want to detect them? Remember: The constructor did not complete, i.e. the object actually does not exist, accessing it would be undefined behaviour!

Comment: Can you change the Route class or is this behavior something you just have to live with? The cleanest solution would be to change Route. But there are ways around it, if you can instead change the type of the array

Comment: Off-topic: don't use magic numbers in your code (10 here within the for loop) – they represent redundant information and if you change the array you might forget to adjust that loop. You can get that size automatically via `sizeof(routes)/sizeof(*routes)` to iterate over all array elements. Actually you could here even use a range based for loop (`for(auto& r : routes) { r.output() }` as the array did not yet decay to a pointer (afterwards that's not possible any more).

Comment: @Aconcagua I updated the post with the code of the constructor in question and the classes. in regard to your comment. I am not sure what you mean by how to handle non-constructed elements. This is a college assignment so the way you see the array created(setting elements to result of the constructor that is being fed raw data) is how the assignment wants it done

Comment: Not only does the following elements not get constructed, all the ones that were constructed are destroyed. That is, there are no array elements at all. (What sensible thing could you do with a partial route anyway?)

Comment: It looks pretty much as if the entire route is broken anyway – from point of higher view (programme's *logic*), does it make any sense at all trying to continue in such a case? What could you do with a *partially* constructed route (assuming you solved your original issue e.g. via the `std::vector` approach)?

Answer (score 0):

Having an array that is partially initialized makes no sense. And you wouldn't even know how many elements are initialized.

You should use a vector and simply create the objects in a loop:

```
std::vector<Route> routes;
// make sure no allocation happens as that would invalidate
// the `const Route &` in the constructor call
routes.reserve(10);
try {
    routes.emplace_back(legArray[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) routes.emplace_back(routes[i], legArray[i + 1]);
    }
}
catch (const char* a) {
    cout << a << endl;
}
for (const auto & route : routes) {
    route.output();
}
```

Comment: Depends... It might not make any sense at all if the route cannot be constructed as a whole – so initial approach that doesn't print any output at all might even be the correct one ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua The question was about trying each element being added to the array. Which I interpreted as wanting whatever routes manage to construct. The try/catch can be moved into the loop if desired but not with the constructor calls as given.

Comment: Hm... Try/catch inside the loop would allow skipping elements, but we'd need to use `routes.back()` then to address the successor. Not sure if this is what the QA actually wants, we'd need to ask ;) I actually meant that the completely unchanged code of the question might be the actually correct one, as partial routes might not be meaningful...

Comment: Side note: `save on allocations [...]` – actually there's a much more important reason why we need this, we not only want to save (for performance?), but absolutely *require* to avoid re-allocations as these would make the reference to `routes[i]` dangling before actual emplacement would take place ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua Good catch. To emplace there must not be an allocation. Even when using push_back on a temporary this would blow up. You would need a named variable to construct the next Route and then `std::move` that into place. But luckily we can reserve space and avoid that problem. Source updated.